# Which is faster for resolving an IP?

Tags: php, dns, exec, resolve, gethostbyaddr

Has anyone done any testing to see which is faster/more efficient/better for resolving an IP address in a PHP script?

This

```
exec('host '. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

or this

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Comment: Why dont you try it yourself :-)

Comment: i had bigger problem - i had to make script that is checking host 100-300 times per seconds. Ended with mysql database with ip's and hostname chached results

Comment: I have tried it myself, but I haven't done extensive testing between the two, which you often find others have in cases like this, which is why I asked. I also am having to repeatedly call the resolution in a loop that could potentially be hundreds of rounds as well.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a native function, then you should use it instead of using an external command.

Using a external command make your program OS dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it yourself but I would think the cost of starting a whole new process would be more than just calling the `gethostbyaddr` function. Going the external executable route also makes you dependent on a lot of other things, like the OS, your path being set up correctly, the possibility that the output of `host` may change, and so on.

Optimisation mantra number 1 is *measure, don't guess!* Number 2 is *only optimise if you have established it's a bottleneck,* so make sure it's actually causing a problem before you waste time trying to fix something irrelevant.

Comment: number 3: hardware is cheaper than people, buy more ram and cpu before developers.

Comment: How do ya establish which function is a bottleneck without measuring it? ;)

Comment: @GeekDrop.com, that's why #1 is there: measure, establish, optimise.